# stylesheet not working with codeigniter

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter.I have created style sheet called `mystyle.css` with a folder structure of `application/styles/mystyle.css`.My view is `first_view.php` with a folder structure of `application/views/first_view.php`.I have placed the href link like this:

```
file:///C|/wamp/www/demo_code/application/styles/mystyle.css.
```

It doesnt work,but it displays the contents with no style.When i use like this

```
href="<?php echo base_url('styles/mystyle.css');?>"
```

the age is displayed with no contents.I didnt understand how this happens.Please help me

```
EDIT
```

My config file contains like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

I first advice u that it is recommended that store your css in assets

```
/www
/code_igniter
    /application
    /assets
        +img
        +css
        +js
    /controllers
    /system
```

then use it in your view as including it

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href='<?echo base_url()?>assets/css/mystyle.css'>
```

into your .htacess file add this

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|_searches|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sample/index.php/$1 [L]
```

also include this assests folder into your `.htaccess file`

Comment: is creation of assets folder required for inserting css files

Comment: no it is not necessary bt if u create then u just need one time include assests into your .htaccess

Comment: @AnazA it is not required but it is a good practice to keep external resources outside of application folder for more about this refer to michel's answer

Comment: @AzamAlvi my .htaccess file contains only 'Deny from all'.

Comment: is that file is inside your application folder or outside the application folder? if it is inside folder then copy it and paste it outside application folder mean root then open it and past code that i have mention and u just need to change name `sample` in line 3 with your website name or your  main folder

Comment: @AzamAlvi I have done like this,i have placed .htaccess outside application,but it shows 500 Internal Server error

Comment: is there an index file in root folder?

Comment: have you checked the `rewrite_module` from your XAMP/WAMP?

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand, that CSS is purely client-side, this has nothing to do with CodeIgniter. **CodeIgniter generates HTML, which is parsed by the clients browser.**

The HTML tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/format.css">
```

instructs your browser to download a separate stylesheet file **`/css/format.css`** which is fetched from the **webserver in a seperate request**.

Your webserver delivers this file, note that the path for all files requested from a webserver is relative to your webservers configured document root.

**`../application/..`** does not look like a folder in document root. The folder is usually called htdocs or public or httpdocs.
I think codeigniter is working with a **central index.php** where all dynamic requests are redirected to. Static files have to be in the same folder or below.

Answer (score 1):

use this code to integrate style sheet

`<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/format.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Answer (score 1):

Change this line by this in confing file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/your_project_name/';
```

if you are running your site on local server then do nothing if your have running on other server then type its name (domain name) and replace with `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

At first change your **folder structure** to

```
 /public/css/mystyle.css (optional)
```

To include a **stylesheet** you can do this at

```
 <head> tag:
```

as

```
<LINK href= "<?=site_url(); ?>public/css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

if doesn't work you **must configure your .htaccess**

Answer (score 0):

Put the stylesheet, js or other resource outside the application folder. it is standard and secure. Use this line to include css or js.

```
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href='<?echo base_url()?>css/mystyle.css' />
```

Comment: have placed styles folder outside application.Sill not works.Is it required to change anything in.htacess file